# How to interface Numpy's ndarrays to store objects in?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I want to store a series of differently sized arrays into one "parent" array. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
    
a1 = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]) 
a2 = np.array([7,3]) 
a3 = np.array([1])

# What I want to do
a_parent = np.ndarray(a1, a2, a3)
    
# Desired output
print(a_parent[0])
>>> [[1 2]
    [3 4]
    [5 6]]
    
print(a_parent[1])
>>> [7 3]
    
print(a_parent[2])
>>> [1]
```

I know this is possible because when I import Matlab cell data using `loadmat` from the `scipy.io` library the data gets converted to a numpy `ndarray` and it behaves exactly like above. I've looked through the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) and I can't find a working example to show how I could do this myself.

Comment: why not just use np.array?

Comment: True @NicolasGervais . `parent_array = np.array([a1,a2,a3])` This should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [5]: a1 = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])  
   ...: a2 = np.array([7,3])  
   ...: a3 = np.array([1])
```

The best way is to make a 'blank' array of the desired dtype and shape:

```
In [6]: a_parent = np.empty(3, object)                                                               
In [7]: a_parent                                                                                     
Out[7]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
```

and 'fill' it from a list of the desired arrays (or other objects):

```
In [13]: a_parent[:] = [a1,a2,a3]                                                                    
In [14]: a_parent                                                                                    
Out[14]: 
array([array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]]), array([7, 3]),
       array([1])], dtype=object)
```

I'm sure `loadmat` uses this method.

Passing the list directly to `np.array` may work, but v1.19 wants us to include the `object` dtype:

```
In [10]: np.array([a1,a2,a3])                                                                        
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[10]: 
array([array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]]), array([7, 3]),
       array([1])], dtype=object)
```

This does not work if the arrays are all the same shape:

```
In [11]: np.array([a1,a1])                                                                           
Out[11]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]]])
```

And for some shape combinations we get an error.

```
In [15]: a_parent[:] = [a3,a3,a3]                                                                    
In [16]: a_parent                                                                                    
Out[16]: array([array([1]), array([1]), array([1])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Though how do I append a new array to a_parent?

Comment: There's a whole family of `np.concatenate` and `stack` functions that create a new array from a list of arrays.  But they can be picky about matching dimensions.  Better to append to a list.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), an `ndarray` is:

> An array object represents a multidimensional, homogeneous array of **fixed-size items**.

So you can't have objects of different sizes. You should then just use this:

```
a_parent = np.array([a1, a2, a3])
```

`np.array` allows elements of differents sizes

Comment: something like this `np.concatenate([a_parent, np.array([1, 2, 3])], axis=0)`

Comment: So I would like to do this a_parent = `np.concatenate([a_parent, a1], axis=0)` and index the last array with a_parent[3]. I'm getting an error

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list and the use `np.array` just like this :

```
a_parent = np.array([a1, a2, a3], dtype=object)
```